problem with apache server displaying index.html instead of flask endpoint
I have the following config files:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/propman.domain.com.conf:
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIDaemonProcess propman_proc python-home=/var/www/propman/.venv processes=1 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup propman_proc

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/propman.domain.com.common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/propman.domain.com.common
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

/etc/apache2/sites-available/propman.domain.common:
LogLevel debug
ServerName propman.domain.com
ServerAlias www.propman.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/propman

WSGIScriptAlias /propman /var/www/propman/test1.wsgi

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/propman_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/propman_access.log combined

And scripts:
/var/www/propman/test1.py:
from flask import Flask
app  = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/propman")
def hello():
    return "Hello world again!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, debug=True)

/var/www/propman/test1.wsgi:
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/propman/')
from test1 import app as application

My problem is that when I access http://propman.domain.com, I see the index.html file instead of the results of the endpoint.
If I shut down apache and run the script in the virtual environment on port 80 and access domain.com/propman, it works as expected (I see Hello world again!) in the browser.
I don't see any warnings or errors in the propman_error log
I believe the problem is in the apache2 configuration files. I have tried variations of
WSGIScriptAlias /propman /var/www/propman/test1.wsgi   
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/propman/test1.wsgi

and
@app.route("/propman")
@app.route("/")

My apache_error log is now clean, but I still the contents of index.html when I visit http://propman.domain.com

I found that flask was not installe in the venv: pipenv install flask.  You really need to check all of the error logs, not just the ones for the site!
